# Accidentally moved Desktop folder ingo /usr/local/bin

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, mv

I ran `mv -n /desktop /user/local/bin` and as a result everything on my desktop is gone. I tried the opposite `mv -n /user/local/bin /desktop` in the hopes of undoing it but now only one of those directories will exist at one time. What should I do? How badly did I screw things up?

Comment: What's in `/desktop` now? All your files PLUS the original content of `/user/local/bin`? In that case you could try to separate the two manually.

Comment: How did you have filesystem permissions to do that? You aren't running as root, are you? And why do you have a `desktop` folder in the root directory?

Comment: I ran `sudo`. As you can tell, my sh*t's messed up.

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of

```
mv /desktop /user/local/bin
```

is

```
mv /user/local/bin/desktop /
```

However:

- I assume you meant `/usr` instead of `/user`. If you really typed `/user`, you have a different problem.
- Don't just type the above command without actually understanding what you've done. You may be royally messing things up by moving directories around arbitrarily.
- Don't run as `root`. If you weren't, you wouldn't have been able to mess it up in the first place (since normal users can't write to `/usr/local`).

Comment: Beat me to it..

Comment: well right now `/desktop` is a directory but /usr/local/bin is not. What should i do to restore order?

Comment: ok everything you said has been right, but you havent helped me fix my problem. Right now I have /desktop as a directory, but /usr/local/bin is not. How can I fix this?

Comment: You probably now have a `/desktop/desktop` also, which is the original contents of `/desktop`. If so, then try: `mv /desktop /usr/local/bin` followed by `mv /usr/local/bin/desktop /`.

Comment: I don't have `/desktop/desktop`. Now `/desktop` has all of its old stuff

Comment: ok, I have both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local` but I'm unsure if having `/usr/bin` is normal? Did I lose `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: If you didn't have a `/desktop/desktop` then I'm afraid I've lost track of what you've done, sorry. Both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` are normal.

Comment: am I screwed? don't I need to move executables to `/usr/local/bin` since it's on my PATH?

Comment: (a) Unfortunately I don't know whether you're screwed or not because I don't know what state your filesystem is in now. (b) If you're asking whether your **have to** move executables to `/usr/local/bin` just because it's on your PATH, then the answer is no. You don't need root privileges to change your own PATH environment variable. Or, you can simply run executables from the current directory with `./whatever`.

Comment: ughhhh it wont let me log into chat

Comment: can I just create the `/bin` folder in `/local`?

Comment: I think we've lost track of what you've done.  Which folder has the original contents of `/desktop`?  Which folder has the contents of `/usr/local/bin`?  (Don't mess with `/usr/bin`, that's unrelated.)

Comment: @blahdiblah @Greg `/desktop` has the contents of `/desktop`. That seems to be 100% fine. Now `/usr/local/bin` is missing. I just found that I have a `/bin` file in my root. Could this be the file?

Comment: No.  `/bin` is another folder that you shouldn't bring in to this.  (Though if `/bin/bin` exists, that would be worth noting.)  To help us track down where everything went, can you give us the output of `history | grep "^mv"` (or at least the history of everything following `mv -n /desktop /usr/local/bin`)

Comment: @blahdiblah This is the output of `history | grep "mv"`:  `363  mv -n desktop/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin`
  `364  sudo mv -n desktop/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin`
 `365  sudo mv -n desktop/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin`
  `395  mv -n /usr/local/bin desktop`
  `396  sudo mv -n /usr/local/bin desktop`
  `398  sudo mv -n desktop /usr/local/bin`
  `421  mv -n /usr/local/bin desktop`
  `422  sudo mv -n /usr/local/bin desktop`
  `429  sudo mv -n desktop /usr/local/bin`
  `434  sudo mv -n desktop/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage`

Comment: `435  sudo mv -n /desktop/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage`
  `436  sudo mv -n ./desktop/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage`
  `437  sudo mv -n desktop/wkhtmltoimage /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage`
  `439  sudo mv -n desktop /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage`
  `442  sudo mv -n desktop /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage`
  `483  mv -n /usr/local/bin /desktop`
  `484  sudo mv -n /usr/local/bin /desktop`
  `516  mv /user/local/bin/desktop /`
  `517  mv /usr/local/bin/desktop /`

Comment: @blahdiblah I know this is a lot of crap to deal with but I'd truly appreciate it if you'd be able to help me out  :)  btw, `history | grep "^mv"` outputs nothing...

Comment: Whew, exciting stuff.  This `396 sudo mv -n /usr/local/bin desktop` looks like you might have moved `/usr/local/bin` to your desktop folder.  Do you have a `bin` folder in there?  (Also, you should have enough rep to sign in to chat, which would be easier than this.)

Comment: @JustinMeltzer let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/657/discussion-between-blahdiblah-and-justin-meltzer)

Comment: @blahdiblah For some reason it's saying I have to login to chat, but I already am logged in. Chat's not working :(  `/desktop` does not have a `bin` or `usr` folder

Answer (score 1):

The `-n` flag should have prevented anything from being overwritten.

The first move: `mv -n /desktop /usr/local/bin` could have done several things:

1. If /usr/local/bin was a directory, then the /desktop should have been placed in it creating /usr/local/bin/desktop
2. If /usr/local/bin did not exist but /usr/local was a directory then /desktop was moved to /usr/local and renamed to 'bin' creating /usr/local/bin with the contents of /desktop.
3. If /usr/local/bin existed and was a file then the `-n` should have just given you an error message.

The second move: `mv -n /usr/local/bin /desktop` was not the opposite if #1 was true. If #1 was true then /usr/local/bin is likely now just /usr/local and what was 'bin' is now in /desktop, but there is a /desktop/desktop

The confusion comes because `mv` has both a **rename** function and a **move** function that depends on what the source and destinations are (i.e., files or directories).

Good luck, do a bunch of `ls`s to see what is where and once you have found everything, read and re-read the man-page for `mv`, then proceed with caution... oh and by the way, as has been said above, operating as root is not a good idea... with great power comes great responsibility, and the ability to trash your system fas

Answer (score 1):

You can always (as `root`) recreate `/usr/local/bin`

Do you have the executable files to move back into it? Maybe not, since you said you *moved* the files, rather than copied them.

The `/bin` directory is not the same thing. It is meant for system binaries, like `bash`.

`/usr/local/bin` is meant for executables installed by the user (hence `/usr/...`)

But your comment about `sudo` suggests that it will be dangerous to do these things *unless* you have a better understanding of the system and the use of `sudo`.

**Don't rush into it**